# How can I read this C code?

Tags: c

I am quite new to C and I can not successfully understand the following code:

```
#include <signal.h> //1
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int); //2
sighandler_t signal (int signo, sighandler_t handler); //3
```

Line 3 is:

signal is a function that takes 2 arguments, one being an integer and the other being a sighandler_t and returns a sighandler_t?

But what is sighandler_t?

Is it a pointer to a function, where the function that is being pointed is a function that takes an argument of type int and returns void?

Can you give an example on how I can use it?

Comment: signal() is depreciated these days.  "man signal" says:    The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also varied historically across different versions of Linux.   Avoid  its  use:use sigaction(2) instead.

Comment: @StarPilot It does, since 16 years ago.

Comment: gcc (at least) recognizes C++ style comments. It is C.

Comment: If you plan to use **function pointers** in `C` consider using **raw pointers** instead.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino This is from a book really. Linux System Programming. What do you mean use raw pointers?

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino; Using function pointer this way becomes easy.

Comment: No C compiler I ever used understands it. I've used several C++ compilers operating on C code. Tthose compilers know about it. So was the C specification updated to include C++ comments, or are you people just relying on the fact that your C++ compiler recognizes it as a comment and presume that it is standard?

Comment: @haccks, I'm just stating that because the OP is new to `C`. IMO, it would be better if he knew exactly what was going on.
Here are some information on **raw function pointers**:
http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex18.html

Comment: @StarPilot; C11: **6.4.9** : *Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters `//`
introduce a comment that includes all multibyte characters up to, but not including, the
next new-line character.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
```

define a new type `sighandler_t` which is *pointer to a function which expects an argument of type `int` and returns nothing*.

Line

```
sighandler_t signal (int signo, sighandler_t handler);
```

declares `signal` a function which expects its first argument of type `int` and second argument of type `sighandler_t` and returns a type `sighandler_t`.
**`sighandler_t` is user defined type** which is ultimately *pointer to a function which expects an argument of type `int` and returns nothing*.

Without `typedef` it would be written as

```
void (*signal(int signo, void (*handler)(int)))(int);
```

which is more confusing.

Comment: I am still confused. Is sighandler_t defined in standard C, or is it just the book I am reading?

Comment: Why would ´signal´ return a ´pointer to a function´ ?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, the only thing I do not understand is, how is the return value of signal useful?

Comment: The return value may be used to call a function of type `sighandler_t`.

Comment: so like handle a signal, and then run a different function?

Comment: @KorayTugay; Yes. You will understand this concept more clearly once you will use it in a program.